# How to associate "open with" programs exactly by file extension rather than file content format?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfce, file-extension, xubuntu

I use a system with Xubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Now Thunar, the file explorer, does include an option where you can right-click a file and choose the (default) application to open a file type with.

Problem is that it doesn't exactly do so as per the exact file extension (.c or .py). It does so as per the encoding of the file contents (I think).

What do I mean?

- For example, Buttercup (an offline password manager) stores it's vaults simply as encrypted text files. The contents are encrypted, if you open it in a text editor, you'll see gibberish text, but it's fundamentally a text file with a .bcup extension.
- Previously I had set the whole "open with (default application)" for files with the .bcup extension to the Buttercup application.
- Next, I set "open with (default application)" for text files with .py extension (Python source code) to Sublime Text.
- And lo and behold, the next time I double click on a .bcup file, instead of opening it in Buttercup, the OS opens it up in Sublime Text.

How do I avoid this phenomenon? How to make the OS associate "open with" applications to exact file extensions instead of file content formatting?

Thanks.

Comment: See if in [this post](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7235) comment #4 is useful.

Comment: It kind of was. Thanks. Though it still requires me to make, install, install icon for each extension.

Comment: Done (padding....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunar mime-types can be defined via an XML file that defines the file
extension via a glob pattern.

In the post
[File types and extension in Thunar](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7235),
in comment #4, user daggoth said this :

> Secipolla has provided the essential links to the right info above.
> But beyond that, we can proceed to create the new mimetype. So
> firstly, open up a terminal as root, and create a new file, kicad.xml,
> in the /usr/share/mime/packages folder. The filename doesn't have to
> be kicad.xml, it can be anything unique like blah.xml too. And again,
> I'm using geany, but you can use your own favourite text editor...
>
> ```
> cd /usr/share/mime/packages
> geany kicad.xml
> ```
>
> And into that new file, plz cut and paste the following basic mimetype
> definition...
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
>   <mime-type type="application/x-kicad-module">
>       <comment>Kicad Module File</comment>
>       <glob weight="60" pattern="*.mod"/>
>       <icon name="application-x-kicad-module"/>
>   </mime-type>
> </mime-info>
> ```
>
> Basically, the xml files in /usr/share/mime/packages contain the
> mimetype definitions for your system. And here we have added a new
> mimetype "application/x-kicad-module". And those files will use the
> generic icon "application-x-kicad-module" (if it exists). But the
> mimetype and icon names I've used here are pure guesswork for this
> example, so plz substitute and replace with more appropriate choices.
>
> But there is already a standard mimetype for *.mod files - an audio
> filetype as you described above. So I've added a " weight=60 " term
> into our xml, to give our new mimetype a priority of 60, which is
> higher than the default of 50. Thus ensuring that our new mimetype
> takes precedence over the existing one.
>
> Okay. Save your file, and exit your text editor. Now we need to
> rebuild the mimetype database.
>
> ```
> cd /usr/share/mime
> update-mime-database $PWD
> ```
>
> And that should do it. Please reboot your system, and then see if
> Thunar detects the new mimetype.

Comment: See also this article from the GNOME wiki: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom-user.html.en